# What does איברא mean?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, maseches-shabbos, maseches-pesachim, chulin-tractate

The word *איברא* only appears a [handful](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90&filters=Talmud&var=1&sort=r&lang=bi) of times in the Talmud. (E.g. Pesachim 104a; Chulin 59b, 60a) it means something like its true, you’re right etc. 
What is the true meaning of this word, it’s literal meaning, how is it formed? 
I would think it’s a verb form of ברא but that wouldn’t make much sense. 
In Shabbos 90b, it is used meaning arm [אבר] but that still doesn’t fit with the above examples.

Comment: Note that in Hebew, Evar or Eivar (אבר  or איבר) is any an organ of the body, not necessarily an arm.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22080&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what Sokoloff records in his dictionary of Babylonian Aramaic:[image: Sokoloff]

To answer the etymological question, therefore, the word comes from Middle Iranian.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find this Somloff dictionary online or otherwise?

Comment: @Shmuel I used a library edition. I it also can be found online in some places.

Comment: Any idea why it’s crazy expensive, and not widely available?

Comment: @Shmuel The dictionaries are big and probably few were published, due to the specificity of the topic. However, you can access much of the dictionary online through the Hebrew Union College's Comprehensive 
Aramaic Lexicon: http://cal.huc.edu/ (see http://cal.huc.edu/oneentry.php?lemma=%29ybr%29%20X&cits=all)

Answer (score 7):

Here is Jastrow on Eivara (a limb), and Ivra (to be sure).  He says that the latter comes from A-V-R, which is a lashon of strength in Aramaic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Marcus Jastrow says the word means "indeed" or "to be sure".

Everytime you have a question concerning Talmudic vocabulary, it would be a good idea to check Jastrow first. A physical copy is a great thing to have on the bookshelf, but you can access the dictionary online [here](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/).